# Fade out and fade in not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please forgive me since I'm new to Jquery/Javascript.
I've created a simple code that seems to work fine in: IE9, Firefox, Safari, Chrome. But for some reason its not working in Opera. The #loader div doesn't seem to fade away.

**This is the code:**

`$(window).load(function () {

$("#loader").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("p").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
     });`

**The code functions as follows.**

1. Load page, (wait until all content/images are loaded before running function).
2. Wait 4 seconds then fade out #loader div.
3. Finally fade in paragraph after 5 seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Change $(window).load to $(document).ready. I don't think your fadeIn/fadeOut methods are even being called right now. Full example below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#loader").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow"); 
  $("p").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just run the function without fully loading the page?

Comment: Your function will be run after the page completes loading.